# jQuery UI Autocomplete with Chrome-like autofill

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, autofill

I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplete functionality and, while I've found a way to implement the autoFill function, I was looking for functionality like in the Google Chrome address bar.  Where the best matching item is auto-filled, but it doesn't interrupt your typing.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at the older jQuery autocomplete plugin, which offers this option built in. The syntax is similar, but instead of having the source as a option you instead initialized it as the first parameter, with this syntax:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete(data, {autoFill: true});
```

The `data` must be either an array of results, or an url that points to a server-side script that generates it. For more info see its documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

---

Do note however that the author of this plugin consider it obsolete, and the jQuery UI autocomplete to be its successor. In a 'How to migrate' post he points users now to, the rational jQuery UI not having the `autofill` option is explained:

> **autoFill:** Gone with no immediate
>   replacement available, for good
>   reasons: The default behaviour when
>   selecting items via keyboard now puts
>   the focussed value into the input,
>   like the Firefox Awesomebar does it.
>   It's not the same as what the autoFill
>   option did, but there should be no
>   need to recreate that effect.

Comment: Here is a link to a more recently updated version of the original, "obsolete" plugin: https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#FELD').autocomplete( 
      source: "ajax/manager.json.php",
      minLength: 0, 
      change: function(event, ui) {
          found = false;
            $(".ui-autocomplete li").each(function(n, element){
              var retval = $(element).text().toUpperCase();
              var retval2 = $($(this).data()).attr('item.autocomplete');
              if ((found == false ) &&(retval == $("#FELD").val().toUpperCase()) )
              {
                $("#FELD").val(retval);
                $("#FELDID").val(retval2.id);
                found = true;
              }
            });
          if ( found == false) { $("#FELDID").val("-1"); }
      }
  }); `enter code here`
```